# The system automatically restarts when opening the browser, IntelliJ IDEA, or WebStorm. How can I resolve this issue?

Tags: windows, system

System Log:

[image]

System Info:

[image]

I couldn't identify the reason causing the issue from the logs. Could you please provide more information or context? Once I have more details, I can assist you in resolving the problem.

Comment: What an odd way to end the question. I don’t see how anybody could help let alone provide *you* with more details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.